# symbol png_init_io, version PNG12_0 not defined in file libpng12.so.0 with link time reference

Tags: python, matplotlib, centos, shared-libraries

I work on CentOS without root access in a virtual environment. When using matplotlib.image to load and save png, I originally got the error:

```
ImportError: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I cloned the libpng to install it locally:

```
git clone git@github.com:glennrp/libpng.git
git checkout origin/libpng12
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${HOME}/local .. && make all instal
```

Now Python seems to find it, but raises following error:

```
ImportError: ~/.venv/lib64/python3.3/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.cpython-33m.so: symbol png_init_io, version PNG12_0 not defined in file libpng12.so.0 with link time reference
```

What can I do to solve that problem?

Comment: libpng12 is an older version : 1.2.xx . ( Your "git" version is 1.6.24 ). Libpng12 source : libpng-1.2.56.tar.gz → https://sourceforge.net/projects/libpng/files/libpng12/1.2.56/libpng-1.2.56.tar.gz/download

Comment: Although I used "git checkout origin/libpng12"? Thanks for the link!